# Flexbox different size childs

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I learn flexbox and I have a first question how to make such a layout of columns as in the picture?  `[`MyCodeFiddle`](`http://jsfiddle.net/1s3bo913/`)`

[layout project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AjAdx.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You can nest flexbox containers:

- One outer container A, `display: flex; flex-direction: column;`
- Inside of that two containers B1 and B2, both `display: flex; flex-direction: row;`
- Inside the first one of those (B1) two containers B1a and B1b
- B1b should again have `display: flex; flex-direction: column;` and contain two DIVs or images (the berry pictures)
- Inside B2 two regular DIVs (no flexbox)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `column` for the 2 vertical `.small-box`es and set `flex: wrap` on the parent. I adjusted the widths so it matches the parent element dimensions.

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  width: 500px;
  height: 400px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.flex-container, .flex-col {
  display: flex;
}

.flex-col {
  flex-direction: column;
}

.large-box {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  background: blue;
}

.small-box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background: yellow;
}

.medium-box {
  width: 250px;
  height: 200px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="large-box">
  </div>
  <div class="flex-col">
    <div class="small-box">
    </div>
    <div class="small-box">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="medium-box">
  </div>
  <div class="medium-box">
  </div>
</div>
```